# Как смещение в .rdata?

Tags: ассемблер, reverse-engineering

Заранее извиняюсь, не совсем понимаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть смещение на нужную мне операцию, в которой есть адрес `(0x028316DC)` как-то связанные с константой в `.rdata`. Так вот, как мне превратить адрес `(0x028316DC)` в смещение для получение константы в `.rdata`.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: 0x028316DC - это относительное смещение относительно конца команды (начала следующей команды). Т.е. чтобы получить адрес, нужно к адресу следующей команды прибавить это смещение. Чтобы из адреса получить смещение от начала файла, нужно из адреса вычесть базовый адрес (image base), он может быть разным при открытии через дизассемблер и при загрузке в отладчике - можно попробовать ориентироваться на адрес, который будет если прокрутить окно с кодом в самый верх (обычно адрес вверху на 0x1000 больше базового адреса). Так получите RVA.

Comment: Дальше из RVA вычитаете начальный RVA секции .rdata и прибавляете физическое смещение начала секции - получаете смещение этого адреса от начала файла.

Comment: То есть в любом случае придется дизассемблировать бинарик,  обычным hex редактором его не получить ?

Comment: Можно без дизассемблера. Дизассемблирование тут ни при чем, тут нужна работа с заголовком файла (PE) - уметь вытаскивать image base, таблицу секций. Некоторые hex редакторы позволяют с заголовком работать, но можно и вручную эти данные получить (хоть и не очень удобно).

Comment: Да мне парсер написать) Спс за помощь

Comment: Если на Python пишите - есть библиотека pefile, можно ее использовать, чтобы с нуля не писать парсер заголовка. Там в том числе и конвертация адресов в смещения есть.